# React JS: При открытии и обновлении страницы появляется модальное окно, которое должно открываться только по клику

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Есть модальное окно Modal, которое вызывается при клике на button. Все, в принципе, работает, вот только при первом открытии и при обновлении страницы, модальное окно появляется само по себе. Как от этого избавиться?
App.js

```
function App() {
  const [coins , setCoins] = useState([]);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('')
  const [modal, setModal] = useState({modal1: true})


useEffect(() => {
  axios.get('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false')
  .then(res => {
    setCoins(res.data)
  }).catch(error => alert('ERROR'))
}, []);

const handleChange = e => {
  setSearch(e.target.value)
}


const filtredCoins = coins.filter(coin => 
  coin.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLocaleLowerCase())
  )

  return (
    <div className="coin-app">
      <div className="coin-search">
          <h1 className="coin-text"> Search a currency </h1>
          <form>
            <input type="text" placeholder="SEARCH" className="coin-input" onChange={handleChange}/>
            <div className="current-data-time">
            < CurrentDateTime  />
            <button className="button_balances" onClick={() => setModal({
              ...modal, modal1: false
            })}>
              Show Balances
            </button>
            </div>
            <Modal 
              isOpened={modal.modal1}
              title={'Balances'}
              onModalClose={() => setModal({...modal, modal1: false})}
              
            >
              <CurrentDateTime/>
              <AsyncCSV/>
              {filtredCoins.map(coin => {
                return <CoinBalance
                key={coin.id}
                name={coin.name} 
                image={coin.image}
                symbol={coin.symbol} 
                balance={coin.high_24h}
              />;
          
            })}
            </Modal>
            
          </form>
          
        </div>
        
        {filtredCoins.map(coin => {
          return <Coin
          key={coin.id}
          name={coin.name} 
          image={coin.image}
          symbol={coin.symbol} 
          marketcap={coin.market_cap}
          price={coin.current_price}
          priceChange={coin.price_change_percentage_24h}
          volume={coin.total_volume}
          
          />;
          
        })}

      </div>
      
  )
  
}

export default App;
```

Само мод. окно
Modal.js

```
import React from "react"



const Modal = props => {
    return (
        <div className={`modal_wrapper ${props.isOpened ? 'open' : 'close'}`} style={{...props.style}}>
            <div className="modal_body">
                <div className="modal_close" onClick={props.onModalClose}>×</div>
                <h2>{props.title}</h2>
                <hr/>
                {props.children}
            </div>
        </div>
        
    )
}


export default Modal
```

Answer (score 0):

const [modal, setModal] = useState({modal1: false})

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]